# adding nearest neighbour constraints to a NStextfield causes it to shrink to the size of the text

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Edit: I found the correct solution and will include it at the bottom of the question

I have a textfield. I constrain the textfield to nearest neighbour, which is in this case the view and when i do this, height for the textfield goes out of my control and matches the size of the text exactly. How can I constrain the text box to nearest neighbour without the text box automatically resizing. Below is an image that shows my constraints and the orange outline of what the textfield wishes to resize to. It also shows that the view will shrink to an expected height of 62 aka the size of the text box.

[image: image adding simple contraints causing the textfield to resize to a new height indicated by the dashed yellow line]

I would add, that when i checked the constraints in inspector, i found that the text box was not always set to first items. when I made the text box the first item in all constraints the width became editable.

Answer:

1) The secret to adding constraints to a text box it to put content hugging as a low priority eg. 250. Look at the above picture and you can see content hugging vertically is at 750 or high priority while content hugging horizontally is at low priority(=250). Therefore i am able to constrain to nearest neighbor for the width which is at low priority but not for the height which is at high priority.
For more info check this documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW2

2) each constraint has a first and second item in the inspector. The second item gets its attributes(eg. size) from the first. double click on the contraints in the size inspector as pictured above to inspect the constraint more closely

Comment: Seems you have other constraints as well which conflicting with each other related with height. So I will suggest to remove existing constraints, and add vertically and horizontally center constraints.

Comment: that is good advice thanks. It worked. Though i wasn't able to resize the text box, i was able to get it in the correct position.

Comment: Let me know how can I help with text box resize. If it helps you, I would like ask you accept my answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to remove existing constraints, and add vertically and horizontally center constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The layout engine does not know what size you want the parent view (your view controller in this case), so it takes the intrinsic content size of the textfield.

Do you want the textfield to be exactly as big as it needs to be? Then don't touch it, your textfield will resize to contain the text, using your constraints to place itself.

Do you want your view controller to have a certain size? (e.g. if you want a specific background image to fit) Then you might want to consider adding constraints to your parent view so that it keeps a certain size or aspect ratio.